# How can i call inline javascript function in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I want to call an inline Javascript function in Angular2 or Angular4.

Following is the sample code of mine.

***.html**

```
<div id="demo" onload="myfunction()"></div>

<script>
  function myfunction() {
console.log("working");
   var map = new AMap.Map("map", 
     { resizeEnable: true, 
      center: [latitude, longitude], 
      zoom: 8
     }); 
}
</script>
```

Is this the right way?
This is not working now.

I am using Amap.map API. I don't see it will support for Angular2. If it supports i will call the typescript function in the component as usual. Now I want to bind the map in the view. So I need to ad this

```
var map = new AMap.Map("map", 
 { resizeEnable: true, 
   center: [latitude, longitude], 
   zoom: 8
 });
```

But getting error because not able to import "AMap"

**Note: Due to third party library i am supposed to try something (inline javascript) like this.**

Comment: Why would you do something like this? What third party library requires you to do that?

Comment: can you throw some light on the library

Comment: Please look at the updated question

Comment: Is the inline working if you do not import Angular?

Comment: @CapeAndCowl: Not its not working if i add in component.html. But it works only if I add the same in index.html

Answer (score 1):

In index.html put below line in tag.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">    
</script>
```

It will include JQUERY in your project.Then in tyescript file you can include your logic as per your requirement

For Ex:

In html file of your component

```
<div id="demo"> 
    <!-----Code-------->
 </div>
```

In your typescript file of component

```
 ngOnInit(){
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#demo').load(() => {
              // Your function Body
              console.log("working");
              var map = new AMap.Map("map", 
               { resizeEnable: true, 
                  center: [latitude, longitude], 
                  zoom: 8
                }); 
          })
       }
 }
```

If you face any issue in adding jquery library, there are other methods too for using it.

Comment: Actually the issue is with AMap. I am not able to import it. Now I tried as u suggest. getting " Cannot find name 'AMap'." . If I import it successfully then i can make it directly without jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

[See this resource that is telling you:](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#html-in-templates)

> Almost all HTML syntax is valid template syntax. The `<script>` element
>   is a notable exception; it is forbidden, eliminating the risk of
>   script injection attacks. In practice, `<script>` is ignored and a
>   warning appears in the browser console.

Answer (score 0):

To import the javascript files, you can include them in the `scripts` array in the `angular-cli.json` file of your project. Include jQuery, AMap js file, and a custom script to call/initialize AMap.

Comment: Hmm.. would be great if you could include examples.